# onclick fires drag event on toggle enabled div

Tags: javascript, css, html, dojo

I have a div that is draggable. The "splitter" that is used for dragging it / toggling it, it's supposed to allow expanding and collapse only on doubleclick. (Or simple drag and expand).

The functionality works fine, but once the div is in the collapsed state, **it repositions/opens up to some 10px width**, when just 'clicking' on the splitter. I.e, single click/mousedown.

I have tried *`stopEvent`*, `return false`, also all other possibilities of fixing it, but it won't stop from expanding on single click

This is not supposed to happen. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle with your code, please?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem I think you will need to add some extra state to your DOM node containing a flag if the object moved or not. If it really moved, then the click event should not be fired.

An example of adding the state:

```
lang.mixin(domNode, {
    moved: false
});
```

Then, when the `Move` event is fired, you set the flag to `true`, for example:

```
moveable.on("Move", function(mv, pos, evt) {
    if (evt.target.moved === false) {
        console.log("Drag detected");
    }
    evt.target.moved = true;
});
```

In the click event handler you will have to verify if the flag is changed to `true` or not and put it back to `false` (for the next moves). For example:

```
on(domNode, "click", function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.moved === false) {
        // Execute your logic here
    }
});
```

Of course, this isn't the most elegant solution (but it works). The most beautiful solution would be that you extend the `Moveable` yourself and make it work to your needs.

I tested it out with a JSFiddle, which you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/7JRr2/).

Comment: Hi Dimitri, Thank you so much for your prompt reply, analysis and effort. The problem is, the anomaly happens even before the "drag"/"move" event is fired. After doing some trial and error I just set the minimum width of the content pane to _the size it moved to_ so that while collapsing or minimising, it does not reach 0px. Instead, it minimizes to 10px. I.e., 10px is the minimum width of the pane.

Comment: I'm not having these issues with my example, so you will need to post some (malfunctioning) code so we can try to solve the problem.